# Xamarin Android Click Button in ListView And Get Item Position

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to make a click button on OnCreateView "Fragment"

the first class is **HomeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter**

is a simple Adapter retrun a view

> HomeScreenAdapter

```
public class HomeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter<Quotes>
{
    List<Quotes> items;
    Activity context;
    public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity context, List<Quotes> items)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override Quotes this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Quotes, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Quotes).Text = item.s_Quotes;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.From).Text = item.s_From;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Category).Text = item.Category;

        return view;
    }
}
```

> Fragment

```
class CrimeFragments : Fragment
{
    ListView Lv;
    List<Quotes> tableItems = new List<Quotes>();
    static Quotes quotes;
    ClipboardManager Cbm;
    ClipData Cd;
    ImageView imageView;
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.crimelayout, container, false);
        Lv = rootView.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.crimeListView);
        Lv.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
        Lv.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this.Activity, tableItems);
        Lv.ItemClick += Lv_ItemClick;
        return rootView;
    }

    private void Lv_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = tableItems[e.Position];
        string cpy = t.s_Quotes + " - " + t.s_From;
        Cbm = (ClipboardManager)Context.GetSystemService(Context.ClipboardService);
        Cd = ClipData.NewPlainText("text", cpy);
        Cbm.PrimaryClip = Cd;
        Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Text Copied", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

> I Want to make this button click not Lv.ItemClick

[image: AXML]

I want make thies buttons independent from Listview

Any One Can Help Me Please ?

Comment: Hi, from your question, do you want to use multiple layout in your `ListView`? But, by `make thies buttons independent from Listview`, what do you mean?

Comment: Hi Thank you @JoeLv-MSFT very much, i found a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Developers I found a solution this worked for me :

- If You've a Adapter class change the **GetView** Function to this :

  ```
      public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
      var item = items[position];
      View view = convertView;
      if (view == null)
      {
          // no view to re-use, create new
          view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Quotes, null);
      }
      view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Quotes).Text = item.s_Quotes;
      view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.From).Text = item.s_From;
      view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Category).Text = item.Category;
      Button btnCopy = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCopy);

      btnCopy.Click += delegate
      {
          Toast.MakeText(this.context, items[position].s_From, ToastLength.Short).Show();
      };
      return view;
  }
  ```